# Cut off a circuit whitest charging a battery

Tags: design

I have a simple (analog) photosensitive circuit designed to turn on at night. My question relates to charging it. I need an easy, preferably cheap method to disable everything in the circuit whilst it is connected to the charger. A Manual switch will not work since it will be fully autonomous.

To simplify, when connected to the charger, the only load seen is the cell/battery (the rest of the circuit is cut off from any current). When disconnected from the charger, the photosensitive circuit becomes operational.

I am fairly new at this kind of thing, so the more simple the explanation the better.

Thanks!

Comment: A MOSFET connected to the battery input (assuming a suitable blocking diode on the battery input) ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugs and sockets that have contacts that "make" or "break" as the plug is inserted. Use one that when you insert the charger plug, it closes the circuit to the battery and disconnects the battery from the rest of the electronics, and when you remove the plug, the battery is reconnected to the electronics.